# Pandoc LaTex PDF headed and footer

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I am using pandoc v 1.18 I want to add header as well as footer text.

I want complete control meaning I want to place heater text at left, center and middle and the same with footer.

But I am unable to get even a single place to show up.

I have the following in my YAML header in my markdown file

```
---
header: This is fancy
footer: So is this
headertext: This is fancy
footertext: So is this
#abstract: This is a pandoc test . . .

documentclass: report
output:
  pdf_document:
    fontsize: 12pt
    mainfont: Roboto
    geometry: [top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]
css : pandoc.css
linkcolor : cyan
toc : true
---
```

I have tried to use `header` and `headertext` separately as well and that did not work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest solution is to add a custom latex header. Create `header.tex` in your working directory and add something like:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Fancy on the right}
\lhead{Fancy on the left}
\cfoot{Fancy in the footer}
```

See the [fancyhdr manual](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for help.

And then compile with `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.pdf -H header.tex`. With Rmarkdown, this can be set in the YAML front matter:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in-header: header.tex
---
```

To be able to set the header with a variable in the YAML like you wanted, you will need to play with the [rmarkdown latex template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex) (see the [pandoc manual section about templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates)) but you'll probably lose the possibility to fine-tune the header and footer with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: This does not work with documentclass:report, which i guess is by design. Choosing documentclass as book gives a few blank pages after toc and title..any Idea how can I remove them

Comment: @krv works fine with me for `documentclass: report` (only, the first page a chapter has no header/footer, which is normal). For `documentclass: book`, the blank pages are here because it is two-sided by default. See here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1683/56508 to remove footer and header from those

Comment: Yup did a recheck works with `documentclass:report` ..Thanks